# How to get a correct end of sentence space for the next sentence if the previous one is followed by \pause?

Tags: beamer, spacing

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Proverbs}

think. Thus (correct)\newline
\pause
think.\pause\ Thus (wrong)

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to get a correct end of sentence space for the next sentence if the previous one is followed by `\pause`?

Comment: Using `...think.\pause\@ Thus ...` seems to work...

Comment: @PeterGrill: Sorry. It does not produce the correct spacing as well. :-)

Comment: Ok, how about `...think.\pause\xspace Thus...` with `\usepackage{xspace}`.  I can not tell the difference between these two output.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Even though your suggestion works but I want to avoid loading an extra package if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `{}` after `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Proverbs}

think. Thus (correct)\newline
\pause
think.\pause{} Thus (correct)

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]